# How to replace every row's string in a column with a new string containing a loop index?

Tags: mysql

A table like this, let's name it 'Foobar' contains several strings in the 'data' column like this:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | data        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | sometextbla |
+----+-------------+
|  2 | Hello world |
+----+-------------+
|  3 | abcbiebuwhi |
+----+-------------+
...
```

I'd like to iterate through all the rows with an MySQL command and replace data's strings with a pre-defined string plus the current index, so the result looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | data        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Testcase 1  |
+----+-------------+
|  2 | Testcase 2  |
+----+-------------+
|  3 | Testcase 3  |
+----+-------------+
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: what ever it is that you are trying to do, you don't need to do it. This is data that can be generated (obviously you are trying to generate it). As such it doesn't need to be stored. Just generate it when you want to display it

Comment: I was thinking there might be an easy MySQL query to do that. The reason for this is that I want to replace company data with dummy data that I can show  in my Bachelor Thesis. Guess I will generate an MySQL update query string with Python then.

Comment: sorry you misunderstood me. What I was saying is that you dont' need to save data that can be generated. If this is a uni project it's a different matter. In that case using python is probably a lot easier than using SQL anyway since SQL sucks at string manipulation while python is very good at it.